# How did 子, meaning "child", become a noun suffix?

Tags: etymology

It's really impressive how 子 [zi] is super productive as a noun suffix. But I can't see any relation of how the idea of "child" could turn into a suffix.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of _diminutives_? E.g. -zinho

Comment: Does this help? https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/31303/what-is-the-meaning-of-%e5%ad%90-in-words-like-%e8%8f%93%e5%ad%90%ea%b3%bc%ec%9e%90-%e5%b8%bd%e5%ad%90%eb%aa%a8%ec%9e%90-or-%e7%8d%85%e5%ad%90%ec%82%ac%ec%9e%90

Comment: This is not unusual among languages. 儿 is the other Chinese diminutive and has a similar literal meaning. I'm pretty sure that in Thai the diminutive is also formed using a word literally meaning "child" except it's a prefix rather than a suffix.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a diminutive suffix, about which you can read these entries:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diminutives_by_language

Comment: While this is true I feel it is a little bit of an oversimplification. While 子 may have begun as a diminutive suffix, there are many examples of common nouns in which it has lost any diminutive meaning and is present only for prosodic reasons, ie, to make a two syllable word out of a one syllable word. 帽子 vs. 帽.

Answer (score 1):

In Chinese, 子 has multiple meanings and usages.

(1) One of them is the noun "child" such as 父与子(the father and the child).

(2) You can also say 孔子 which means Confucius. Here 子 is used as a suffix to some great ancient scholars. The usage here is similar as we put "Dr." before the person who has a Ph.D. degree.

(3) The case you mentioned which the 子 is used as the noun suffix is another usage, such as 桌子，椅子，瓶子，镜子(table, chair, bottle, mirror). It doesn't really have a relationship with the meaning "child".